# Angular ngModel is not Binding Data

Tags: html, angular, angular2-forms

when i click on Edit Button Email textbox is Binding but why Salary textbox is not Binding

```
<form class="form-horizontal" novalidate [formGroup]="EmployeeForm">
    <fieldset>   
<div [ngClass]="{'has-error':(EmployeeForm.get('Email').touched||
            EmployeeForm.get('Email').dirty) && !EmployeeForm.get('Email').valid}">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" formControlName="Email" [(ngModel)]="EmployeeForm.Email" />
        </div>

        <div [ngClass]="{'has-error':(EmployeeForm.get('sal').touched||
            EmployeeForm.get('sal').dirty) && !EmployeeForm.get('sal').valid}">
            <b>Salary...</b>
            <input type="number" formControlName="sal" [(ngModel)]="EmployeeForm.sal" />
        </div>
```

**EditButtonCode**

This is my FormGroup Code Here im validating my columns

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        // this.CascadingComponent.GetCountry();
        this.EmployeeForm = this.fb.group({
            Emp_Id: ['', [Validators.required]],
            EmpName: ['', [Validators.required]],
            Psw: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(6)])],
            Gen: ['', [Validators.required]],
            //   Cpsw: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(6)]]
            //}, { validator: this.checkIfMatchingPasswords('Psw', 'Cpsw')
            Email: ['', [Validators.required]],
            sal: ['', [Validators.required]],
            Cnt_Name: ['', [Validators.required]],
            Dept_Name:['', [Validators.required]]
        })

    }

    EditEmp(Selected: Employee) {
            this.EmployeeForm.setValue(Selected);
        }
```

Comment: where is your Edit Button also please add full code for better understanding

Comment: Can you provide a JS Fiddle?

Comment: Im Gettin Data Object
City_Id
:
1
City_Name
:
"Guntoor"
Cnt_Id
:
1
Cnt_Name
:
"India"
Date
:
"2015-01-01T00:00:00"
Dept_Id
:
1
Dept_Name
:
"Dotnet"
Email
:
"Ghouse"
EmpName
:
"Ghouse"
Emp_Id
:
100
Gen
:
1
Psw
:
"123"
Sts_Id
:
1
Sts_Name
:
"AndhraPradesh"
sal
:
15000    When i click on Edit Button this is Refelect in textbox

Comment: Plase Reffer my updated Code